# Remove hidden values within string

Tags: unity, c#, text

I tried removing the Unicode Whitespaces in the string using `words[len].Trim()` but still there's still an extra character.

Every letter represents the coordinate of where the letter is. As you can see there's an extra coordinate/value and it is always located at the end of the string. (dont mind the '# tries')
Can you help me Identify what is the extra invisible unicode and what to do in order for it to be removed?

[image]

```
private string[] FisherShuffle(string[] words) {
    int len = words.Length;
    while(len > 0) {
        float index = Mathf.Floor(Random.Range(0f, 1f) * len);
        len--;
        var temp = words[len].Trim();
        words[len] = words[(int)index];
        words[(int)index] = temp;
    }
    return words;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have found out that the ASCII value is 13. I also have tried using `TrimEnd('\n','\n')` & `words[len].TrimEnd(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())` to no avail

```
private string[] FisherShuffle(string[] words) {
    int len = words.Length;
    int index;
    string temp;
    while(len > 0) {
        index = (int) Mathf.Floor(Random.Range(0f, len));
        len--;
        //temp = words[len].TrimEnd('\n','\r');
        temp = words[len].TrimEnd(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
        words[len] = words[index];
        words[index] = temp;
    }
    return words;
}
```

Comment: You know, instead of `float index = Mathf.Floor(Random.Range(0f, 1f) * len)` and later casting to int, you could just write `int index = Random.Range(0, len)`

Comment: Have you tried walking over the characters in the string and printing (int)temp[i] for each one, to learn exactly what character code it is?

Comment: @DMGregory I haven't tried it. Good Idea but I got like 613 words stored in the text passed on parameter. Do you have recommendations for improving functions speed?

Comment: @DMGregory Found out that value of ASCII is 13 I also have tried using `TrimEnd('\r','\n')` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [String.Trim()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Trim) tells us

> White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard. The Trim() method removes any leading and trailing characters that produce a return value of true when they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

One option is to use the overload [String.Trim(Char[])](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Trim_System_Char___) to specify characters that you aren't expecting. To debug, you could iterate over the string printing each character and the corresponding result of `Char.IsWhiteSpace`.

Please consider refactor as well.

```
private string[] FisherShuffle(string[] words) {
    int len = words.Length;
    int i;
    string tmp;

    while(len > 0) {
        i = (int) Random.Range(0, (float) len);
        len--;

        tmp = words[len].Trim();
        words[len] = words[i];
        words[i] = tmp;
    }
    return words;
}
```

Comment: If I would use `String.Trim(Char[])` for every letter in the string I don't have to do, `String.Trim()` ? From what I have read in other posts that `String Trim()` would any whitespaces from the beginning and end of string.

Comment: Please read the documentation which is linked above or google "C# String Trim", etc.